# How do I deserialize different JSON representations of the same class?

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, json.net

I have a C# class that clients might represent in two different JSON schemas, depending on the context.

```
    public class Point
    {
        [JsonProperty("x")]
        public double? X { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("y")]
        public double? Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class Multipoint
    {
        [JsonProperty("points")]
        public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
    }
```

where `Multipoint` is just a list of `Point`.

The JSON syntax for a `Point` is:

`{"x" : <x>, "y" : <y>}`

which I can successfully deserialize using Json.NET.

However, the JSON syntax for a `Multipoint` is

`{"points" : [[ <x1>, <y1> ] , [ <x2>, <y2> ], ... ]}`

for which I get the following error when trying to deserialize:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Deserialization.Point' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Right, yes, because the serializer doesn't know how to assign elements of the inner array (an ordinate pair) to the X and Y properties.

So, this can be done by creating a custom derializer to assign the correct ordinate to the correct property. However, what I don't understand is how I can assign 2 different serializers to my type.

Comment: Please attach snippet from real JSON which should be deserialized. This is a structure that can be deserialized without any custom serializers. You have probably a mismatch between real JSON structure and your classes. Try paste your JSON here: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a custom `ItemConverterType` for the `Multipoint.Points` property.

```
public class Multipoint
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "points", ItemConverterType = typeof(MyPointsConverter))]
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

The converter should implement [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. This approach worked for me. I don't quite understand, however, why it's deserializing a single Point, rather that a List<Point>.